# How to avoid congesting/stalling/deadlocking an executorservice with recursive callable

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, executorservice

All the threads in an ExecutorService are busy with tasks that wait for tasks that are stuck in the queue of the executor service.

Example code:

```
ExecutorService es=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
        Set<Future<Set<String>>> outerSet=new HashSet<>();
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            outerSet.add(es.submit(new Callable<Set<String>>() {

                @Override
                public Set<String> call() throws Exception {
                    Thread.sleep(10000); //to simulate work
                    Set<Future<String>> innerSet=new HashSet<>();
                    for(int j=0;j<8;j++) {
                        int k=j;
                        innerSet.add(es.submit(new Callable<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public String call() throws Exception {
                                return "number "+k+" in inner loop";
                            }

                        }));
                    }
                    Set<String> out=new HashSet<>();
                    while(!innerSet.isEmpty()) {            //we are stuck at this loop because all the
                        for(Future<String> f:innerSet) {    //callable in innerSet are stuckin the queue
                            if(f.isDone()) {                //of es and can't start since all the threads
                                out.add(f.get());           //in es are busy waiting for them to finish
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return out;
                }
            }));
        }
```

Are there any way to avoid this other than by making more threadpools for each layer or by having a threadpool that is not fixed in size?

A practical example would be if some callables are submitted to ForkJoinPool.commonPool() and then these tasks use objects that also submit to the commonPool in one of their methods.

Comment: Have you considered a `ForkJoinPool` for this? It almost looks like a text book example for it.

Comment: Wouldn't that just block on join() just as if I had called get() on a normal future?

Comment: Not exactly, since `ForkJoinPool` is a work stealing pool, so a thread blocked on `join()` can do other work if available, whereas with your code a blocked thread will just be one thread less for work.

Comment: @Kayaman you can get a work stealing pool without using `ForkJoinPool` using `Executors.newWorkStealingPool` function. The only difference woud be that in `ForkJoinPool` you have to specify the way in which your task will recurse explicitly.

Comment: @Shankha057 well `Executors.newWorkStealingPool` returns a `ForkJoinPool`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a `ForkJoinPool`. It was made for this situation.

Whereas your solution blocks a thread permanently while it's waiting for its subtasks to finish, the work stealing `ForkJoinPool` can perform work while in `join()`. This makes it efficient for these kinds of situations where you may have a variable number of small (and often recursive) tasks that are being run. With a regular thread-pool you would need to oversize it, to make sure that you don't run out of threads.

With `CompletableFuture` you need to handle a lot more of the actual planning/scheduling yourself, and it will be more complex to tune if you decide to change things. With `FJP` the only thing you need to tune is the amount of threads in the pool, with `CF` you need to think about `then` vs. `thenAsync` as well.

Comment: @Shankha057 then it's a good thing, there's work for all threads.

Comment: `newWorkStealPool()` -> https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newWorkStealingPool() executor is implementation of `FJP`. I guess, this would work as well.

Comment: @SachithDickwella it really doesn't matter **how** you build the `FJP`. As long as you use it correctly and use `join()` to allow the work stealing to happen.

Comment: If the threads are busy, `FJP` would adjust the thread count accordingly and may use multiple queues to reduce contention.

Comment: @SachithDickwella additional threads would only be involved in case of managed blocking, not by default. If the situation is as given in the question, it looks like a pretty standard case.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying to decompose the work to use completion stages via `CompletableFuture`

`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(outerTask)
    .thenCompose(CompletableFuture.allOf(innerTasks)`

That way your outer task doesn’t hog the execution thread while processing inner tasks, but you still get a Future that resolves when the entire job is done. It can be hard to split those stages up if they’re too tightly coupled though.

Comment: The stages are tightly coupled together here. It's a direct hierarchical dependency between the two types of stages so it's not possible to decompose as outer creates inners and are dependent for their return values to finish their jobs. The fork-join algorithm is useful to solve this

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you are suggesting which basically is based on the hypothesis that there is a possible resolution if the number of threads are more than the number of task, will not work here, if you are already allocating a single thread pool. You may try it to see it. It's a simple case of deadlock as you have stated in the comments of your code.

In such a case, use two separate thread pools, one for the outer and another for the inner. And when the task from the inner pool completes, simply return back the value to the outer.

Or you can simply create a thread on the fly, get the work done in it, get the result and return it back to the outer.